# Why can't I connect directly with my Gmail OpenID?

Tags: support, openid, login, google-openid

When I connect with Google to Super User, it shows me an OpenID of the form

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=xxx
```

I then added it to my profile and tried to logout and reconnect with it, but Google says the page request is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, on the **login page** you want to click the smaller Google Profile button, not the larger Google (Gmail) button.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use your Google profile URL as your OpenID.
That is, `http://www.google.com/profiles/xxx`